# Question on pure mathematics helping climate change research

Tags: gm.general-mathematics, applied-mathematics

While I am a pure mathematics tenured professor, still at a relatively young age, and fairly passionate about my area of research, I cannot help but feel that it may be more useful to humanity if I could use some of my education and skills towards climate change research. I am fully aware that most positive changes will come from politics rather than science but one should not try to go into areas that has zero talent, which leads to my

**Question**:

Does anyone have any hint or recourses on whether there is any climate change related research that pure mathematics skills are most helpful?

Comment: I know John Baez got interested in geoengineering a while back. I don't think he was surely trying to apply any deep mathematical ideas to climate science, though.

Comment: The late Andrew Majda wrote a nice paper about math challenges in this area https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/cpa.21401?casa_token=kS5lIu2As7IAAAAA:GZOkTnyrR1kIhC48yrPRolIO1MxIjQ5lEqepn3_Gxi-YjEUQLW5Z4RVPKlOrs4nfRWJeDye2dJCKZmTu

Comment: Some leads: https://blogs.ams.org/blogonmathblogs/2019/06/24/planet-math/ , https://blogs.ams.org/blogonmathblogs/tag/climate-change/ , https://johncarlosbaez.wordpress.com/2013/10/13/what-is-climate-change-and-what-to-do-about-it/

Comment: The technological solutions are available, but the socio-political will is not. //  Don't forget that modeling CC doesn't solve what the mainstream now regards as the real, serious problem of CC. // On a long-term basis, R&D in fusion via tokamaks (perhaps also laser fusion) has potential and most certainly involves some interesting math on magnetohydrodynamics.

Comment: Check out this: https://johncarlosbaez.wordpress.com/2023/11/25/what-can-mathematicians-do-about-climate-change/

Answer (score 4):

[Chris Budd](https://www.gresham.ac.uk/speakers/professor-chris-budd) is one mathematician who has made a career in numerical weather prediction. He describes some of the challenges in [The Mathematics of Climate Change.](https://www.gresham.ac.uk/sites/default/files/2018-11-13_ChrisBudd_MathsOfClimateChange-T.pdf) He explains the need for ‘simple’ mathematical models of climate, which can explain what comes out of the massive computer simulation of the Navier-Stokes equations that the IPCC uses to make its predictions. There is room for mathematical and physical ingenuity there. Some examples:

One challenge for experts in dynamical systems is to investigate [tipping points,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tipping_points_in_the_climate_system) rapid and irreversible changes when parameters are changed only slightly.

[Extreme event attribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_event_attribution) is a  particularly urgent area of research where experts in statistical inference and inverse problems can make influential contributions: How to combine data and models to link cause and effect.

More generally mathematicians can make a difference in educating the public on the meaning of statistical predictions. What do error bars in climate change models mean? Some in the general public dismiss the IPCC predictions because they are "uncertain". For more on this see [Climatology needs Mathematics.](https://teachers-climate-guide.fi/mathematics/)

---

<sub>A similar question can be asked about physics. One of our former students in theoretical physics, an expert in the analysis of the massive data produced by particle accelerators, switched his career to climatology and became co-founder of the [World Weather Attribution](https://www.worldweatherattribution.org/geert-jan-van-oldenborgh-1961-2021/) initiative. I find his life story inspirational.</sub>